# Pass umlauts (special characters) from angular client to java server

Tags: java, angularjs, json, string, character-encoding

I'm trying to pass values, like: Wei**ß** from UI to MPC controller,  but somewhere "on the way" to controller, the value being corrupet, and becomes Wei**Ã**

Iw as trying to figure a way to set UTF-8 encoding somewhere to fix this issue, but I just can't figure it out..

Here is how I send it from Angular Controller:

```
JSON.stringify(map)
```

This is how it looks when I print it on client side

```
Object {Color: "Grün", Color: "Weiß"}
```

This is how I receive it at server side controller

```
public String upload(@RequestParam("nvMap") JSONObject  jObject)
```

And after that it is already corruped.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you looked at what's happening on the wire, e.g. with Wireshark?

Comment: No, I'm not familliar with that. I did chekc my request paylod though and it appears correctly there

Comment: Then I suggest you look it up as a tool to add to your repertoire :) It's (occasionally) vital to be able to look at exactly what request has been sent, in terms of the raw bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll play with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's (more) likely that the text is stored as intended in the database, but you see the wrong output when using the value from the backend. That's because the "corrupted" text is made of two bytes that, when interpreted as (the variable-length) UTF-8 lead to the desired character (plus [an invisible character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/009f/index.htm))

```
@Test
public void testTranscoding() throws Exception {
    byte[] utf8Bytes = "Weiß".getBytes("UTF-8");
    String asUtf8 = new String(utf8Bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
    assertEquals(asUtf8, "WeiÃ\u009F");
}
```